# Sql Server Collation conflict occurs only in pypyodbc, not in Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, python-2.7, pypyodbc

I received this message in a python 2.7 script execution:
u'42000', u'[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Latin1_General_CI_AI" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the charindex operation.'

I researched for similar problems here and found some in a pure sql topic. I tried the use of COLLATE but noted that the query runs fine in MSSql Management Studio, so the problem seems related to the pypyodbc.

I tried the 3 drivers available ('SQL Server', 'SQL Server Native Client 11.0' and 'ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server') in my pypyodbc connection but the same error occurs.

Is this a problem from pypyodbc-1.3.5.2? There is a solution other than install pyodbc?

Here is the query:

```
consulta_aia =u"""
SELECT
       PRO.idProcesso as NIS
      ,CAT.nomCategoria
      ,PRO.Sigla
      ,PRO.codano as AnoProcesso
      ,PRO.codnumero as NumeroProcesso
      ,SIT.nomSituacao as nomSituacao
      ,FAS.nomFase
      ,STA.nomStatus
      ,PST.datInicio as datInicio
      ,case 
            when INF.desInfracao like '%(FL)%' then 'FL'
            when INF.desInfracao like '%(FA)%' then 'FA'
            when INF.desInfracao like '%(MI)%' then 'MI'
            when INF.desInfracao like '%(PE)%' then 'PE'
            when INF.desInfracao like '%(UC)%' then 'UC'
            when INF.desInfracao like '%(CO)%' then 'CO'
            when INF.desInfracao like '%(ORN)%' then 'ORN'
            when INF.desInfracao like '%(QU)%' then 'QU'
            when INF.desInfracao like '%(APP)%' then 'APP'
            when INF.desInfracao like '%(APM)%' then 'APM'
            when INF.desInfracao like '%(APP' then 'APP'
            when INF.desInfracao like '%(FG)%' then 'FG'
            when INF.desInfracao like '%(PO)%' then 'PO'
            when INF.desInfracao like '%FAUNA%' OR desinfr LIKE '%FAUNA%' then 'FA'
            when INF.desInfracao like '%TRATOS DOMÉSTICOS%' then 'FA'
            when INF.desInfracao like '%TRATOS SILVESTRES%' then 'FA'
            when INF.desInfracao like '%MOTOSSERRA%' then 'FL'
            when INF.desInfracao like '%MOTOSERRA%' then 'FL'
            when INF.desInfracao like '%PESCA%' OR desinfr LIKE '%PESCA%' then 'PE'
            when INF.desInfracao like '%VEGETAÇÃO NATURAL EM LOCA%' then 'FL'
            when INF.desInfracao like '%RESERVA LEGAL%' then 'FL'
            when INF.desInfracao like '%VEGETAÇÃO NATIVA%' then 'FL'
            when INF.desInfracao like '%VEGETAÇÃO DE ESPÉCIES%' then 'FL'
            when INF.desInfracao like '%ORIGEM VEGETAL%' then 'FL'
            when INF.desInfracao like '%DESTRUIR FLORESTAS%' then 'FL'
            when INF.desInfracao like '%MADEIRA%' then 'FL'
            when INF.desInfracao like '%PRESERVAÇÃO PERMANENTE%' then 'APP'
            when INF.desInfracao like '%FOGO%' OR desinfr LIKE '%FOGO%' then 'FG'
            when INF.desInfracao like '%VEGETAÇÃO NATIVA%' OR desinfr LIKE '%ARVORES NATIVAS%' then 'FL'
            when INF.desInfracao like '%EMBARGO%' then 'EMB'
            when INF.desInfracao like '%MINER%' OR desinfr LIKE '%MINER%' then 'MI'
            when INF.desInfracao like '%UNIDADE DE CONSERV%' then 'UC'
            else 'OUT'
       end as CatInfra
      ,INF.desInfracao as NomeInfracao
      ,PMAUTO.[desinfr] as DescricaoInfracao
      ,upper(PES.nomPessoa) as NomeAutuado
      ,convert(varchar(19), AIA.datInfracao,20) as DataInfracao
      ,PMAUTO.[bopfm] as NumeroBO
      ,case when len(MUN.codIBGE)>6 then MUN.codIBGE else '3550308' end as CodIBGE
      ,MUN.nomMunicipio as PRO_Municipio
      ,case
           when PMAUTO.[area] > 0 then PMAUTO.[area]
           when MFOA.[AreaDegradada] > 0 then MFOA.[AreaDegradada]
           else  MFOA.[AreaTotal] 
       end as AreaAfetada
      ,case 
            when aiaalt.LocalInfracao is not null then SUBSTRING(aiaalt.LocalInfracao.STAsText(), charindex(' -2', aiaalt.LocalInfracao.STAsText()), 19)
            when len(PMAUTO.[gpsy]) > 1 then PMAUTO.[gpsy] 
            else convert(varchar(20), CEA.latitude, 3) 
       end as Latitude
      ,case 
            when aiaalt.LocalInfracao is not null and aiaalt.LocalInfracao.STAsText() like 'POINT%' then SUBSTRING(aiaalt.LocalInfracao.STAsText(), 8, 16)
            when aiaalt.LocalInfracao is not null and aiaalt.LocalInfracao.STAsText() like 'POLYGON%' then SUBSTRING(aiaalt.LocalInfracao.STAsText(), 11, 16)
            when aiaalt.LocalInfracao is not null and aiaalt.LocalInfracao.STAsText() like 'MULTIPOLYGON%' then SUBSTRING(aiaalt.LocalInfracao.STAsText(), 17, 16)
            when len(PMAUTO.[gpsx]) > 1 then PMAUTO.[gpsx] 
            else convert(varchar(20), CEA.longitude, 3) 
       end as Longitude
      ,convert( varchar(30), PST.datAtualiza, 121) as datAtualiza
  from sigam.dbo.PROCESSO PRO 
  inner join sigam.dbo.PRODETALHE PRD on PRD.idProcesso = PRO.idProcesso
  left join sigam.dbo.CATEGORIA CAT on CAT.idCategoria = PRD.idCategoria
  left join sigam.dbo.PMAUTO on PMAUTO.idProcDet = PRD.idProcDet
  left join sigam.dbo.AIA on AIA.idProcDet = PRD.idProcDet 
  left join sigam.dbo.INFRACAO INF on INF.idInfracao = AIA.idInfracao
  left join sigam.dbo.PESSOA PES on PES.idPessoa = PRO.idInteressado
  left join sigam.dbo.MUNICIPIO MUN on MUN.idMunicipio = PRO.idMunicipio
  left join sigam.dbo.PROCSITU PST on PST.idProcSitua = PRD.idProcSitua
  left join sigam.dbo.SITUACAO SIT on SIT.idSituacao = PST.idSituacao
  left join sigam.dbo.[STATUS] STA on STA.idStatus = SIT.idStatus  
  left join sigam.dbo.FASE FAS on FAS.idFase = SIT.idFase
  left join [sigam].[dbo].[AIAPM_LOCALOCORRENCIA_ALT] as aiaalt on aiaalt.idProcesso = PRD.idProcesso
  left join [SmaFiscalizacaoDb-integracao].dbo.autoinfracaoambiental PMAIA on PMAIA.[IdentificadorAutoInfracao] = AIA.[IdentificadorAutoInfracaoSIOPM]
  left join [SmaFiscalizacaoDb-integracao].dbo.ocorrencia OCO on OCO.id = PMAIA.ocorrencia_id
  left join [SmaFiscalizacaoDb-integracao].dbo.encerramentoocorrencia ENC on ENC.Ocorrencia_id = OCO.id
  left join [SmaFiscalizacaoDb-integracao].[dbo].[AreaIntervencaoOcorrenciaAmbiental] as AIO on AIO.id = PMAIA.AreaIntervencaoOcorrenciaAmbiental_id
  left join [SmaFiscalizacaoDb-integracao].[dbo].[MeioFisicoOcorrenciaAmbiental] as MFOA on AIO.Id = MFOA.AreaIntervencaoOcorrenciaAmbiental_id
  left join [SmaFiscalizacaoDb-integracao].dbo.ComplementoEncerramentoAmbiental CEA on CEA.EncerramentoOcorrencia_id = ENC.id
  WHERE nomCategoria = 'AIA - AUTO DE INFRAÇÃO AMBIENTAL'
  AND pro.codano >= '1980' AND pro.codano <= year(getdate())
  AND ( lower(STA.nomStatus) NOT LIKE '%sem efeito%' OR lower(STA.nomStatus) IS NULL )
  AND PRO.codnumero NOT LIKE '%88888888%'
  --AND PST.datAtualiza >= '{0}'
  AND aiaalt.LocalInfracao is not null
  order by PRO.codano, PRO.codNumero desc
"""
```

This is the connection:

```
# string de conexao com o bd de origem
print "{} - Iniciando conexao ao SIGAM".format(time.strftime("%x %X"))
#odbc_sigam = py_odbc_conn2('sigsql01', 'master', 'usrsig', '@@S.1')
odbc_sigam = pypyodbc.connect(u'Driver={SQL Server};Server=sigsql01;Database=master;uid=usrsig;pwd=@@S.1')
print "{} - Conectado ao SIGAM".format(time.strftime("%x %X"))
```

And, of course, this is the piece of code where the error occurs:

```
# seleciona os registros a serem incluidos (todos os registros do select)
print u"\n{0} - Realizando consulta no banco de dados de origem.".format(time.strftime('%x %X'))
registros = odbc_origem.cursor().execute(sql_dados).fetchall()
print u"\n{0} - Consulta realizada. Iniciando processamento do(s) {1} registro(s)".format(time.strftime('%x %X'),str(len(registros)))
```

The main script calls a module to execute this query, so is too extensive to put it whole here. I'm not sure if it is of any relevance, but the main script has the line # -*- coding: latin1 -*- and the module that does the query has the line # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-.